# Cycles F12 render without tiles?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I like how rendering works in viewport - displaying the whole image all the time, and making it sharper every second. Is it possible to disable tiles for F12 too?

Comment: Hello :). It is indeed possible. Just check *Progressive Refine* in the render tab, under tile size. But keep in mind it's also a lot slower.

Comment: @JachymMichal I would accept it, if it would posted as an answer. Thanks.